# OpenCV USB-camera does not work on Raspberry Pi 4 32-bit

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

When I am trying to start videocapuring with opencv and python, it simply does not load. Does not show any problems, does not return anything. NOTHING!!!

The code is the simpliest one:

```
import cv2
import sys

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
   ret, frame = video_capture.read()

   cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the result of running this program

[image]

if I run code line by line, this is where it gets stuck

[image]

If I press Ctrl+C during execution of last line this is what it tells me:

```
Trying to dispose element pipeline0, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL state.

You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before

dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.

This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the

application or some element.
```

Comment: Does your camera show up in `lsusb`? What about `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` ?

Comment: yes, in lsusb it shows my camera and this is my output for `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`: 
`bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
 /dev/video10
 /dev/video11
 /dev/video12
 /dev/video18

bcm2835-isp (platform:bcm2835-isp):
 /dev/video13
 /dev/video14
 /dev/video15
 /dev/video16

USB Live camera : USB Live came (usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1):
 /dev/video0
 /dev/video1
`

Comment: is there a display attached to your raspberry pi? does the raspberry pi recognize and use this display? or are you connected via SSH?

Comment: I am connected via ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not really a solution, but a 0-effort thing to try is specify the video backend like this:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, CAP_V4L2)
```